# When I add space in EditText, it crashes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am passing values from Activity A to Activity B and storing the values in EditText since I need it to be editable The purpose is to provide editable option, once any update done is updated to database, When i edit the text in edit text box by entering few characters it accepts and application runs but when i insert space between the text eg: name[space]initial then run the application crashes.

I saw the log and it says illegal argument , I don know whats causing the problem ..

> the values from previous activity are retrieved here
>   rname=getIntent().getExtras().getString("NAME"); remail=getIntent().getExtras().getString("EMAIL"); rphone=getIntent().getExtras().getString("PHONE NO"); raddress=getIntent().getExtras().getString("ADDRESS"); rcity=getIntent().getExtras().getString("CITY"); rcityloc=getIntent().getExtras().getString("CITYLOCATION"); rqual=getIntent().getExtras().getString("QUALIFICATION"); rgender=getIntent().getExtras().getString("GENDER");

the above received values are being stored in edit text boxes as below
ename=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.namebox); ename.setText(rname,TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

eemail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailbox);
                eemail.setText(remail,TextView.BufferType.NORMAL);

```
            ephone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phonebox);
            ephone.setText(rphone,TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

            eaddress=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.addressbox);
            eaddress.setText(raddress,TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

            ecity=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.citybox);
            ecity.setText(rcity,TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

            ecityloc=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.citylocbox);
            ecityloc.setText(rcityloc,TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

            equal=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.qualbox);
            equal.setText(rqual,TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

            egender=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.genderbox);
                                       gender.setText(rgender,TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

3.the editing if present is done and is sent to server with the below code
edit text values are converted to string and then sent to server

```
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(UrlPath.Upath+"User_profile_update?sid=" + sid + "&name=" +sname+ "&phone=" + sphone + "&address=" + saddress + "&city=" + scity + "&city_location=" + scityloc + "&qualification=" +squal + "&gender=" +sgender );
```

1. the log output

> FATAL EXCEPTION : main
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal charecter in query at
>   and displays
>   the post method url mentioned above in 3

Comment: could you post some related code as well as the actual log stacktrace please?

Comment: Please post your code and the stacktrace!

Comment: The Title of this question is not... good.

Comment: Can you post your source code please?

Comment: Maybe the string is used for some kind of a command, but without the code it's hard to say.

Comment: 07-30 13:32:05.947: E/AndroidRuntime(4170): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 13:32:05.947: E/AndroidRuntime(4170): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at

Comment: this is not enough, please post Your code...and the offcut from your logcat that You wrote here

Comment: Please post your some part of code..

Comment: good....and now the logcat output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand all this stuff the right way, You trying to do some stuff with the editText entries and a HttpPost. I think to add blanks between this HttpPost will crash the app, because whitespaces are not allowed. Try to replace all whitespaces with %20